# Issue with spacing using TableLayout and TableRow

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I have the following setup in an XML file:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/table_more_features"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_blue" >
    ...
<TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/cell_top"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_foo"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:text="Foo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_bar"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:text="Bar" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_woo"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:text="Woo" />
    </TableRow>
...
</TableLayout>
```

The result looks like [image: this]

Seems like no matter what I try I cannot get an even spacing between the three TextViews, the first always takes the majority of the room.  I am trying to have all 3 spaced evenly horizontally.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though in my AS your code spaces out evenly you could try the following:

- to each TextView add `android:layout_width="0dp"`
- (optional) to the Table row add `android:weightSum="1"`